# What was Darth Maul's birth name?

Tags: star-wars, sith, names, darth-maul

When a person becomes a Sith, he changes his name. For example:

- Palpatine took (or was given) the name Sidious
- Count Dooku took (or was given) the name Tyranus
- Anakin Skywalker was given the name Darth Vader.

What was Darth Maul's name before he became a Sith?

---

Note: the idea for this question came from https://www.moviemistakes.com/member542/answers/page49

Comment: Wikipedia doesn't seem to know.

Comment: Apparently it was also Maul, according to the Legends book "Darth Plagueis", which isn't cannon anymore.

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/109742/why-did-vader-and-maul-abandon-their-name-while-the-other-sith-lords-in-the-movi?rq=1

Comment: Dennis.  http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/151211125301-01-rex-features-5490589a-exlarge-169.jpg

Comment: it was Garth Paul.

Comment: Canon, not cannon!!!!

Comment: Sheev, probably. Or Martha.

Comment: James. It was James.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

As far as we know, Maul *is* Darth Maul's pre-Sith name. [He was born a Nightbrother](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Maul#Early_life) and has brothers with similarly evil-sounding names: [Savage Opress](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Savage_Opress) and [Feral](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Feral). Maul's last name may be considered "Opress" since that's the last name of his brother Savage; on the other hand Maul's mother, [Talzin](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Talzin), doesn't seem to have a last name.

Not all Sith change their names when they change their title. There is at least one other example (albeit from Legends) of a Sith who used his birth name: [Revan / Darth Revan](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Revan). Most Sith change their names in order to help hide their identity (which was especially important for, say, Palpatine/Sidious). Maul didn't need to change his name because he didn't have a public identity that needed to be kept separate from his Sith identity (and he was conspicuous enough with his tattoos, which he received as a boy).

Comment: If he would've been born in Hawaii, he would've been called Darth Maui

Comment: Maul himself [indicates](https://youtu.be/Av7kJUQ0oJo?t=4m) he had a prior name but no longer recalls it. We have no guarantee this is true, but he does claim it (unless he tells us it was a lie later).

Comment: Seems like they change their names mostly if they don't sound intimidating enough already.  Darth Alicia  just isn't all that scary.

Comment: Darth (M)Alak approves.

Answer (score 25):

It may very well simply be Maul.

In *Star Wars: Rebels*, Mauls rejects the Sith and says this:

> Formerly Darth, now just Maul.

Since he no longer considers himself a Sith, and dropped the "Darth" title, it doesn't make sense that he'd keep his Sith name if it wasn't also his real name.

Comment: Formally, or formerly?

Comment: I'm fascinated that you mentioned *Rebels* but didn't mention that he [claimed](https://youtu.be/Av7kJUQ0oJo?t=4m) to have a name he doesn't recall. He could be lying, but worth mentioning. Unless it's made explicit that he lied later in the episode?

Answer (score 7):

We may never know. He mentioned in Rebels that he had a name once, but he has long since forgotten it. I suppose he had to leave it behind when Palpatine made him into Maul

Answer (score 6):

In the book Darth Plagueis, Maul is taken as an infant by Sidious from his mother. The child was named Maul.

> Palpatine, in his urge to know more about the dark side than what Plagueis teaches him, manages to make a visit to the world of Dathomir, where he encounters a Dathomirian woman who gives him a Zabrak infant simply known as Maul. Palpatine later has Maul sent to Mustafar, where he could be nurtured at his young age in the dark side of the Force.
>
> [Star Wars fandom page for Darth Plagueis](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Plagueis_(novel))

Later, Maul's existence is made known to Plagueis, who permits (and encourages) Sidious to retain Maul, not as an apprentice, but merely as an assassin (akin to the relationship between Dooku and Ventris during the Clone Wars).

Comment: This is correct, but it's worth noting that the novel is Legends now (i.e. not canon).

Comment: As far as degree of Legends go, this is just barely over the line. The author, James Luceno, also wrote Tarkin (which *is* canon) that references many of the events in Darth Plagueis directly.

Answer (score 2):

In the book, 'Darth Maul, Lockdown', in the prison he was known by the name 'Jangannath' this could be his first name.

Answer (score 0):

The Wookieepedia canon gives information. Here's the exact text:

> Their son was born on the planet Iridonia and was given the name Maul—the same Maul who would later be feared and dreaded as Darth Maul, Dark Lord of the Sith as the Sith apprentice to Darth Sidious.
>
> [Star Wars fandom page for Maul's father](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Maul%27s_father)

Comment: I'm not sure why you would refer to Wookieepedia as canon.

Comment: That article is referring to Legends information. The banner in the upper right shows it (the banner would be black and say "Canon" for a canon article).

Comment: The citations on that page make it look like this information is from the Legends novel The Wrath of Darth Maul.